# Export sqldatasource to excel not just list or gridview

Tags: asp.net, excel, sqldatasource

I'm trying to export my listview, but not just the visible listview, I want to export the entire contents of the sqldatasource.  The query returns 20 columns, only a small set (5) are displayed on the listview.  Is there a way i can export the entire 20 columns to excel file?

I have this so far:

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SearchResults.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    //I want to chagne this:
    this.ResultsListView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
 }
```

instead of this line:

```
    this.ResultsListView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
```

I would like to do something like:

```
    this.sqldatasource.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
```

But obviously SqlDataSource doesn't have a RenderControl method.  Is there a clean way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a DataTable from the DataView returned by the SqlDataSource and export that to Excel. The resulting DataTable will contain all the columns.

Example:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView) this.sqldatasource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)).ToTable();
```

Now take this DataTable and export that. [Google export DataTable to Excel.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Export%20DataTable%20to%20Excel&aq=f&oq=export%20d&aqs=chrome.0.59j0j57j5j60j61.3249j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

If you are fine with using third-party libraries, look into [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). You can export a DataTable to Excel in, literally, 2 lines of code. The rest would be the code to set the headers and flush the Response.

Here's an example: http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use CSV rather than excel for plain data, but the new version of Excel does have the advantage of compression.

You can use the [OpenXMLSDK](http://lateral8.com/articles/2010/3/5/openxml-sdk-20-export-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx) to directly export to XLSX or the [FileHelpers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12170/FileHelpers-v2-0-Delimited-CSV-or-Fixed-Data-Impor) library to export to CSV.